# Volume of a solid - triple integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

How to find the volume of a solid enclosed by the planes $x=0$, $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$, $y=0$ and $-x+y+z=0$, and the surface $z=sin(x)$.

I can see that the surface is a cylinder, but I can´t see the limits of integration for z. I thought: $0\leq y\leq x-z$, $0\leq z \leq sin (x)$ and $0\leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$. Is it correct?

Comment: I can't see that it's a cylinder: how do you see that?

Comment: The surface z is a cylinder.

Comment: Yes, but it intersects the $-x + y + z = 0$ plane so it looks to me as if the volume is sort of a wedge, flat on one side and curved on the other.

Comment: Yes, only  $z= sin(x)$ is a cylinder, the other boundary is a plane.